# Identity is not working in my ASP.NET 7 web api application, the token is ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identity, .net-7.0

I am trying to create a new project, it's an API in .NET 7, to serve a mobile app.  I've had issues all day, no sample I found actually worked and I've just been trying until I get somewhere.  I am at a point where any URL I call returns a 401 unless I mark it as [AllowAnonymous].  My issue is simple.  I called the method that generates a token, copied from a Microsoft sample.  I am in fact getting a token back.  However when I make a call with that token, I still get a 401 back.  I assume something is wrong in my config, which follows:

```
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.
        var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
        builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<Take5Context>(options =>
          options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
                
        builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultUI()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        builder.Services.AddScoped<JwtHandler>();

        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(k =>
        {
            k.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            k.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(p =>
        {
            var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("JWTToken:key");
            p.SaveToken = true;
            p.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = "JWKToekn:key",
                ValidAudience = "JWKToekn:Audience",
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key)
            };
        });

        builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
        });

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        app.MapRazorPages();

        app.Run();
```

Comment: "However when I make a call with that token, "How you make a call with that token ? By postman or ?

Comment: I was using postman.  I spent the whole day going through tutorials that didn't work and asked my first question 2 hours ago.  I've solved it now, as usual, SO isn't really helpful :)

Comment: I'm sorry that your question didn't get a timely response, but luckily you solved it at last.

Comment: I don't think SO is here to give you immediate answers.